# How to retrieve the value of a many2many field for each sale order?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I've created a many2many field in the sale.order model that it's related with fleet.vehicle model (id).

How it's showed in the follow image:

IMAGE 1: [image]

Well, the 'x_vehiculo' field is a multi-selection field, How it's showed in the follow image:

IMAGE 2: [image]

The idea is that for each sale order i can to store more that 1 vehicle.

The trouble is that i can't see the value for of x_vehiculo' field for each sale order when i make a query in the SGB Postgresql (PgAdmin III).

IMAGE 3: [image]

There is any way to can retrieve values of 'x_vehicle' multi-selection field for each sale.order?

Please if somebody could help me. I'd be very gratefull.

Thanks you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The relation is not stored in the `sale_order` table.  Since it's `many2many`, it is stored in a relational table.  Based on your screenshot, your relational table is this one: `x_fleet_vehicle_sale_order_rel`

To query for the vehicles, you have to join through this table like so:

```
select so.name, fv.name
from sale_order so
left join x_fleet_vehicle_sale_order_rel rel on (rel.sale_order_id = so.id)
left join fleet_vehicle fv on (fv.id = rel.fleet_vehicle_id);
```

This will give you a row for each combination of `sale.order` and `fleet.vehicle`.  If you want to group them by sale order you can do this:

```
select so.name, array_agg(fv.name) as vehicles
from sale_order so
left join x_fleet_vehicle_sale_order_rel rel on (rel.sale_order_id = so.id)
left join fleet_vehicle fv on (fv.id = rel.fleet_vehicle_id)
group by so.name;
```

This will return one row for each `sale.order` with a list of `fleet.vehicle` names attached to that order.

Comment: Thanks so much i can understand it and do it with your support.

Answer (score 1):

The field isn't going to be available on the table you declared it, it's a Many2many relationship so a separate 'join' table is going to be created for it, the name of that table is

`x_fleet_vehicle_sale_order_rel`

That table will contain the fields `sale_order_id` and `fleet_vehicle_id`

So you should be querying that table instead of the table where you declared `x_vehiculo`